# Javascript Loop inside another loop make 2 lists

Tags: javascript

I have some data which looks like this:

```
{
    "mains": [{
        "id": "454",
        "name": "main 1",
        "subs": [{
            "id": "32",
            "name": "sub 1"
        }, {
            "id": "23",
            "name": "sub 2"
        }, {
            "id": "54",
            "name": "sub 3"
        }],
        "image": null
    }, {
        "id": "654",
        "name": "main 2",
        "subs": [{
            "id": "87",
            "name": "sub 1"
        }, {
            "id": "78",
            "name": "sub 2"
        }],
        "image": null
    }]
}
```

From this I need create 2 lists:

For creating the first list with all the mains …I’ve done this:

```
mainlist = [];
sublist = [];

for (var i = 0; i < data.mains.length; i++) {
    var obj = data.mains[i];
    var mnlst =  obj.name;
    mainlist.push(mnlst);
}

console.log(mainlist);
```

In this example it will return the names of the mains resulting in 2 names (in this case).

Now what I need to do it to get the names of the subs for each main

So sublist (in this case will return)

“sub 1, sub 2 and sub 3” for main 1 and “sub 1 and sub 2” for main 2 etc…

How can I do this?

Comment: you get for every main a single sub list. how should the `sublist` look like?

Comment: Basically I'll have a select so if I was to select Main 1 .... it would then give me "sub1", "sub 2", "sub 3" ... So the 1st list will populate the dropdown menu and the other will give me the subs for every selection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use another data structure for the sublist with `name` of main as key.

```js
var data = { "mains": [{ "id": "454", "name": "main 1", "subs": [{ "id": "32", "name": "sub 1" }, { "id": "23", "name": "sub 2" }, { "id": "54", "name": "sub 3" }], "image": null }, { "id": "654", "name": "main 2", "subs": [{ "id": "87", "name": "sub 1" }, { "id": "78", "name": "sub 2" }], "image": null }] },
    mainlist = [],
    sublist = Object.create(null);

data.mains.forEach(function (main) {
    mainlist.push(main.name);
    sublist[main.name] = main.subs.map(function (sub) {
        return sub.name;
    });
})

console.log(mainlist);
console.log(sublist['main 1']);
console.log(sublist);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 2):

you actually had the right idea in your question title - nested loops, you need to iterate over the internal `subs` in each "main" like this:

```
mainlist = [];
sublist = {};
for (var i = 0; i < data.mains.length; i++) {
    var obj = data.mains[i];
    var mnlst =  obj.name;
    mainlist.push(mnlst);
    var tempArr = [];
    for(var j = 0; j < obj.subs.length ; j++){
       var subObj = obj.subs[j];
       var sblst =  subObj.name;
       tempArr.push(sblst);
    }
    sublist[mnlst] = tempArr;
}
```

I've changed `sublist` to be an Object and I place the "subs" in to a temp array before inserting them into `sublist` as keyd arrays (where the key is the main name) now you can use it like `sublist['main 2']` to receive all the relevant subs

Comment: Good solution. Exactly how I would have done it for him to show how the nested loop works.

Comment: thank you @Pegues - but actually after Nina's clarification with the OP - I understand it's not what he needs, her answer is the best one for this situation

Comment: Rereading what the OP posted, it now sounds like he was looking for the solution Nina provided. It is quite easy for you to modify your code to meet the OP need, but yes, Nina's solution would be better. Thank's for pointing out that I needed to reread the OP!!! Please modify your solution so I don't have to remove your upvote!

Comment: @Pegues - you are correct, I was considering deleting my answer but updating it is a better solution :-) have a great weekend!

Answer (score 0):

Let's modify you code.

```
mainlist = [];
sublist = [];

for (var i = 0; i < data.mains.length; i++) {

var obj = data.mains[i];

var mnlst =  obj.name;

//--[Start Modification]--
var subArr = obj.subs;
for(var j = 0; j < subArr.length; j++)
{
 var subName = subArr[i].name;
 //Here you have subject name, do whatever you want to do with it.
}
//--[End Modification]--

 mainlist.push(mnlst);

}

console.log(mainlist);
```